# Laravel many to many: check only one relationship of same category before attaching

Tags: php, laravel

in my laravel app I have a many to many relationhip between user and badges, where an user can only select a badge of a given category (can't have more than one badge of the same category).

Users will select one badge of each given badge category from a selectable.

So what I want to do is check if there is a badge relationship belonging to the selected category, if there is not then I attach the id, if already one exists, I detach current one and then attach new one.

Migrations:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'user_badge', 'badge_id', 'user_id');
    }
public function badges()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Badge', 'user_badge', 'user_id', 'badge_id');
    }

Schema::create('badges', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('badgecategory_id')->index();
            $table->foreign('badgecategory_id')->references('id')->on('badgecategories')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('icon')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Schema::create('user_badge', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedInteger('user_id')->index()->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->unsignedInteger('badge_id')->nullable()->index();
            $table->foreign('badge_id')->references('id')->on('badges')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Now some pseudo code

```
$hasBadgeId = $badge = where badge category is givenCategoryId

if($hasBadgeId)
{
    $user->badges()->dettach($hasBadgeId);
    $user->badges()->attach($badgeId);
}
else
{
    $user->badges()->attach($badgeId);
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#inline-relationship-existence-queries see if `whereRelation` helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got a couple approaches that can handle this, but they both involve querying the `->badges()` relationship of the current `$user`:

1. Check for a single Badge Association for the given Category ID:

```
$badge = Badge::find(1); // Replace 1 with whatever Badge ID you want to Attach

// If you're only expecting a Single Badge for a given Category (optimistic case):
$existingBadge = $user->badges()->where('badgecategory_id', $badge->badgecategory_id)->first();

if ($existingBadge) {
  $user->badges()->detach($existingBadge->id);
}

// Finally, Attach the new Badge
$user->badges()->attach($badge->id);
```

2. Query for all Badge Associations for the given Category ID:

```
// If there's a chance there's already multiple Badges for the same Category (pessimistic case)
$existingBadgeIds = $user->badges()->where('badgecategory_id', $categoryId)->pluck('id');

if (!$existingBadgeIds->empty()) {
  $user->badges()->detach($existingBadgeIds->toArray());
}

// Finally, Attach the new Badge
$user->badges()->attach($badge->id);
```

As you can see, you can check for a single Badge for the given Category and detach it, or query for multiple, and detach them. The Multiple approach will work for 1-∞, so it's actually the safer approach here, in case you have existing bad data in there, but they should both work

Comment: Edited to use `pluck('id')` instead of get an a loop

Comment: It does `public function detach($ids = null, $touch = true)` ^^ `attach()` in the other hand doesnt, you need to use `syncWithoutDetaching()`

Comment: @N69S Confirmed; it does indeed accept an array. One of my older answers suggested that it didn't, which I used as a reference here. Slightly re-adjusted to use Collection, then `->toArray()`, but same idea. Thanks for the edit 

Comment: using `toArray()` earlier, make it easier to check for empty result with just `if ($existingBadgeIds) ` since empty array return false in boolean.

Comment: Also fair. I typically just use `if(!empty([]))` instead of just `if([])`; much easier to tell what is happening at a glance (in my opinion anyway; some linters will say don't use the inverse for an `if()` statement, or use `unless()` if available, etc.).